# Get DateTime.Now with milliseconds precision

Tags: c#, datetime, precision, milliseconds

How can I exactly construct a time stamp of actual time with milliseconds precision?

I need something like 16.4.2013 9:48:00:123. Is this possible? I have an application, where I sample values 10 times per second, and I need to show them in a graph.

Comment: Related http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882581.aspx

Comment: Be aware that a number of the answers are using `hh` for hours (standard time). In the case of a timestamp (and in many other cases) this should probably be paired with `tt` (am/pm) or replaced by `HH` (military time).

Answer (score 379):

> How can I exactly construct a time stamp of actual time with milliseconds precision?

I suspect you mean millisecond *accuracy*. `DateTime` has a lot of precision, but is fairly coarse in terms of accuracy. Generally speaking, you can't. Usually the system clock (which is where `DateTime.Now` gets its data from) has a resolution of around 10-15 ms. See Eric Lippert's [blog post about precision and accuracy](https://learn.microsoft.com/archive/blogs/ericlippert/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime) for more details.

If you need more accurate timing than this, you may want to look into using an NTP client.

However, it's not clear that you really need millisecond accuracy here. If you don't care about the *exact* timing - you just want to show the samples in the right order, with "pretty good" accuracy, then the system clock should be fine. I'd advise you to use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now` though, to avoid time zone issues around daylight saving transitions, etc.

If your question is *actually* just around converting a `DateTime` to a string with millisecond precision, I'd suggest using:

```
string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(Note that unlike your sample, this is sortable and less likely to cause confusion around whether it's meant to be "month/day/year" or "day/month/year".)

Comment: @antonio: With no more information than "don't works" I can't provide any more help.

Comment: Yes, I can provide more info:
"{0:yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.UtcNow -> 20180502 11:07:20.000
Win32.GetSystemTime(ref stime) -> 2018,2,5,11,7,20,0 (y m d h mm ss ms)
I can create a instance of date time with milliseconds:
var dt = new DateTime(2018, 5, 2, 19, 34, 55, 200);
"{0:yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.fff}", dt -> 20180502 19:34:55.200
.Net compact framework, Windows Embedded Compact 7, on ARM Cortex-A8

Comment: @antonio: So it sounds like the version of .NET you're using on the hardware you're using simply doesn't provide subsecond accuracy - or you happened to call it on a second boundary. (If you keep hitting `DateTime.UtcNow` repeatedly, does it only ever increment once per second? You haven't shown that.)

Comment: When I retrieve Ticks from DateTime.Now, the value come truncated: Ticks 636534596580000000
DateTime from Ticks 20180205 20:34:18.000. 
the limitation is in the hard/software, i think. 
I have using Stopwatch class, instead
Thanks Jon

Comment: @antonio: It's probably worth creating a new question with full details of the device involved at this point.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am struggling to understand 2020-09-04T14:29:40.101935+02:00 the miliseconds part here, why is it like 101395 ? I mean i expecte 1 second to have like 1000 ms , and this number looks bigger than that ? What does the last 101395 actually represents in a UTC format ?

Comment: @kuldeep: That's not milliseconds, that's microseconds. But I've no idea where that came from - I suspect you should ask a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet .. somehow i am unable to ask a new question on SO. This was saved in postgres DB as timestamptz from  datetime.UtcNow field  from .net core app !

Comment: @kuldeep: I'm afraid if you've asked sufficiently bad questions to be question-banned, I'm not going to try to bypass that by getting into what *should* be another question via comments. I suggest you edit your old questions to be better, to try to remove the ban.

Answer (score 144):

This should work:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff");
```

If you don't need it to be displayed and just need to know the time difference, well don't convert it to a String. Just leave it as, `DateTime.Now();`

And use `TimeSpan` to know the difference between time intervals:

Example

```
DateTime start;
TimeSpan time;

start = DateTime.Now;

//Do something here

time = DateTime.Now - start;
label1.Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}", time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));
```

Comment: I need compute with it, so I can't convert it to string.

Comment: Note that the most precision for _sub-seconds_ is apparently 7, as in `"hh.mm.ss.fffffff"`.

Answer (score 29):

I was looking for a similar solution, base on what was suggested on this thread, I use the following 
    `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff")` 
, and it work like charm. Note: that `.fff` are the precision numbers that you wish to capture.

Comment: If the date is in afternoon (4PM) will shows as in the morning. **FIX:** Use `HH` (military time) or add `tt` (PM or AM). 
As shown in this example: https://repl.it/KGr3/1

Answer (score 23):

Use DateTime Structure with milliseconds and format like this:

```
string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
timestamp = timestamp.Replace("-", ".");
```

Answer (score 17):

[Pyromancer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032451/get-datetime-now-with-milliseconds-precision/16032507#16032507) seems pretty good to me, but maybe you wanted:

```
DateTime.Now.Millisecond
```

But if you are comparing dates, TimeSpan is the way to go.

Comment: Note: If you're comparing the difference between two DateTimes as a TimeSpan, you need `TotalMilliseconds`. Milliseconds holds the current Milliseconds counter, which is never greater than 1000, whereas TotalMilliseconds holds the total milliseconds elapsed since the epoch.

Answer (score 6):

If you still want a date instead of a string like the other answers, just add this extension method.

```
public static DateTime ToMillisecondPrecision(this DateTime d) {
    return new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute,
                        d.Second, d.Millisecond, d.Kind);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand the question, you can go for:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dateTimeInMilliseconds = dateTime.AddTicks(-1 * dateTime.Ticks % 10000);
```

This will cut off ticks smaller than 1 millisecond.

Comment: Yes, but the actual resolution of DateTime.Now may not be more than about 16 ms.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to construct a new `DateTime` instance from the source `DateTime` value:

```
// current date and time
var now = DateTime.Now;

// modified date and time with millisecond accuracy
var msec = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond, now.Kind);
```

There's no need to do any to-string and from-string conversions, and it's also very well understandable and readable code.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with `DateTime.UtcNow` and `DateTime.Now` is that, depending on the computer and operating system, it may only be accurate to between 10 and 15 milliseconds.  However, on windows computers one can use by using the low level function [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) to get microsecond accuracy, see the function `GetTimeStamp()` below.

```
    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern void GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out FileTime pFileTime);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FileTime  {
        public const long FILETIME_TO_DATETIMETICKS = 504911232000000000;   // 146097 = days in 400 year Gregorian calendar cycle. 504911232000000000 = 4 * 146097 * 86400 * 1E7
        public uint TimeLow;    // least significant digits
        public uint TimeHigh;   // most sifnificant digits
        public long TimeStamp_FileTimeTicks { get { return TimeHigh * 4294967296 + TimeLow; } }     // ticks since 1-Jan-1601 (1 tick = 100 nanosecs). 4294967296 = 2^32
        public DateTime dateTime { get { return new DateTime(TimeStamp_FileTimeTicks + FILETIME_TO_DATETIMETICKS); } }
    }

    public static DateTime GetTimeStamp() { 
        FileTime ft; GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(out ft);
        return ft.dateTime;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been searching this so long. Is it cause any performance issues and is it safe to use production code?

Answer (score 0):

try using datetime.now.ticks.  this provides nanosecond precision. taking the delta of two ticks (stoptick - starttick)/10,000 is the millisecond of specified interval.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score -2):

```
public long millis() {
  return (long.MaxValue + DateTime.Now.ToBinary()) / 10000;
}
```

If you want microseconds, just change `10000` to `10`, and if you want the 10th of micro, delete `/ 10000`.

Answer (score -3):

DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmssffff")