# How to specify precision for datetimeoffset for lambda expression in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public DateTimeOffset OverTrgt { get; set; }
```

If I set `OverTrgt` to some value and used in lambda expression

```
Ctxt.Table.Where(O.Col <= OverTrgt)
```

it generates dynamic SQL

```
exec sp_executesql N'query',N'@p__linq__0 datetimeoffset(7)',@p__linq__0='2015-12-02 19:00:41.5045591 +05:30'
```

but I want

```
exec sp_executesql N'query',N'@p__linq__0 datetimeoffset(0)',@p__linq__0='2015-12-02 19:00:41.5045591 +05:30'
```

Change is `p__linq__0 datetimeoffset(0)`. How can I do it?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032451/get-datetime-now-with-milliseconds-precision