# Timing Sql Queries with ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

NET Entity Data Model in an Asp.net MVC web application. The database is up in Azure. I am trying to time my Sql Queries like this with the start and end time either side of the query.

```
start = DateTime.Now;
var query = item.Database.SqlQuery<CustomerQuery>(queryString);
end = DateTime.Now;
```

I am calculating the time it took like this

```
Duration = end.Subtract(start);
```

Now no matter how many results are being returned, sometimes in the thousands the time is practically the same.

Why is this? and is there a way of getting a more accurate time

Comment: you might use `ToList()` or alike on the result to actually materialize the results (i.e. actually fetch them). Also, don't use DateTime.Now, use Stopwatch.

Comment: If you want to time queries, use SQL Profiler. If you also want to time network delays etc, add Glimpse to your application and check the profiling information it collects for SQL access. Don't try to write this yourself, as in this case you have *two* bugs: First you don't execute the query, second you use an inaccurate method to calculate duration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not expert in this stack, but seems that SqlQuery returns DbRawSqlQuery object, that encapsulates the query, but doesn't execute it. As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679164(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%28System.Type,System.String,System.Object[]%29) says "A DbRawSqlQuery object that will execute the query when it is enumerated."

So you should materialize the query, for example by calling `ToList()`.

```
var query = item.Database.SqlQuery<CustomerQuery>(queryString).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @3615 this work perfectly now. I was Doing the query.ToList() when i was calling the view which was out of the start and end time

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime.Now method is not the best way to clocking milliseconds, you can read more about it in the answer from Jon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032451/get-datetime-now-with-milliseconds-precision). You should instead use the [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class which can be used like this.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

In the method

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var query = item.Database.SqlQuery<CustomerQuery>(queryString);
sw.Stop();

var totalTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: @GertArnold using DateTime to calculate durations can easily lead to this behaviour, if execution is fast enough. Stopwatch doesn't use clock time, instead it read a high-speed performance counter when starting and ending. The Ellapsed properties translate the difference to Ticks, milliseconds etc

Comment: Yes, but just saying *use Stopwatch* is not an answer.

Comment: @GertArnold You are right. I should have adressed the issue instead of just posting a solution. I will take the critic with me till my next answer here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure, you might also be able to tap into the Application Insights.  You can configure your application to send information up to Azure.

See

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-query-performance/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net/