# How to do a time logger class wrapper in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, logging, time, fluent-migrator

I have a lot (around a thousand) of `FluentMigrator` `Migration` classes that started timing out on our build server.

For those who haven't worked with `FluentMigrator` - Migrations are working in such way that all your migrations inherit from `Migration` class that has `Up()` and `Down()` methods that run SQL scripts for db migrations - simple and easy.

Now being lazy I have introduced a `LoggingMigration` class that logs the time when migration starts running (and simply replaced `: Migration` to `: LoggingMigration` in VS for that project).

```
public class LoggingMigration : Migration
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }

    public LoggingMigration()
    {
        this.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Start {0} - TIME: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", this.GetType().Name, StartTime);
    }

    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to also do a time on how long migration was running to make it easier to see which migrations take long.

I was thinking of using destructor like:

```
    ~LoggingMigration()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End(?) {0} - TIME: {1}", this.GetType().Name, DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime));
    }
```

but thing is just to [volatile and unpredictable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032451/get-datetime-now-with-milliseconds-precision#answer-16032517)

**How to add mechanism that would run after `Up()` method in child class finishes?
Or some other way that does the job?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about overriding a protected method instead of the public one:

```
public abstract class Migration
{
    // ...

    protected DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }

    public Migration()
    {
        this.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Start {0} - TIME: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", this.GetType().Name, StartTime);
    }

    public void Up()
    {
        OverrideUp();
        Console.WriteLine("End(?) {0} - TIME: {1}", this.GetType().Name, DateTime.Now.Substracts(StartTime));
    }

    public void Down()
    {
        // ...
        OverrideDown();
    }

    protected abstract void OverrideUp();
    protected abstract void OverrideDown();
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I can't modify Migration class it comes from FluentMigrator but I could introduce class that is inheriting from Migrator (like LoggingMigrator). You are suggesting to replace `Up()` in all current Migrations with `OverrideUp()` correct?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius That's right. Either that or you could use custom attributes, but I'd stick to the object oriented way.

Answer (score -1):

Create decorator for migration class. 
It's will look something like:

```
public class LoggingMigrationDecorator : Migration {
        private Migration _migrationClass;
        public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }

        public LoggingMigrationDecorator (Migration toDecorate)
                {
                     _migrationClass = toDecorate;
                    this.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                    Console.WriteLine("Start {0} - TIME: {1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", this.GetType().Name, StartTime);
                }

                public override void Up()
                {
                 toDecorate.Up();
                 stopTimerFunction(); // your function that will stop timer and do something with result

                }



      public override void Down()
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of decorator pattern : 
http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern