# How to convert string into date time with milliseconds in C#

Tags: c#

How do I convert this string into a date time with milliseconds

> 03/04/2019 15:16:57.73
>
> The format is day/month/year hour:minutes:seconds.milliseconds.

I tried it like this:

```
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";

var year = dateTime.Substring(0, 4);
var month = dateTime.Substring(4, 2);
var day = dateTime.Substring(6,2);
var hour = dateTime.Substring(8, 2);
var minute = dateTime.Substring(10, 2);
var seconds = dateTime.Substring(12, 2);
var miiliseconds = dateTime.Substring(14, 2);
var stringDate = $@"{day}/{month}/{year} {hour}:{minute}:{seconds}.{miiliseconds}";
var transactioDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I get an error of

> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DateTime.Now with milliseconds precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16032451/get-datetime-now-with-milliseconds-precision)

Comment: Are you trying to parse a string, or out put a string

Comment: I don't want it to be string I want it to be date time.

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain it actually came from a long line of string. I need it to be in date time format

Comment: How many milliseconds would you expect in a second? Currently you have `73` - should this be `730` or `073`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you don't need substrings at all.

Just put your date string right into `ParseExact` and you will get what you want.

However the error there is because you have different milliseconds format: it expects you will put **three** digits there but you passed only **two**:

`var dateTime = "03/04/2019 15:16:57.73";`

`var format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff";` - this is the fix.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what was wrong. I';ll mark it as answer after 6 minutes.

Comment: Just for clarity, parsing as `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ff` implies that the `.73` in the `dateTime` string is 730ms. Is that what the OP wants?